# MLCP cant perform import

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I am trying to use MLCP to import an archive that I created through an MLCP export. My script is the following:

```
IMPORT -host localhost -port 10187 -username admin -password abc123 
-input_file_path ./output/*.zip 
-input_file_type archive
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Error setting document properties for /some/path/file: 
Cannot update server-maintained properties
```

That will occur for many files of many types. The searches I have done for that error indicated that I should set the **maintain last modified** prop in my db to false, which I did, but I am still getting the error.

Then following the list of errors for each file it errors on, I get:

```
(SessionImpl.throwIllegalState): Cannot commit without an active transaction
```

repeated a few times.

I am using MLCP's `ContentPump.runCommand()` to run the script, and am executing an xquery script to set **maintain last modified** to false. However, I have tried running the script directly in a command prompt and setting **maintain last modified** to false manually in the admin console, and have gotten the same results.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge `last-modified` is the only property that is server-maintained, and not by default either. Set both `maintain last modified` and `maintain directory last modified` to false, and double check the change got applied correctly by opening Admin UI from fresh, and checking the database settings (again).

Also make sure you changed settings of the right database. Is the app-server running on port 10187 connected to the right database?

After you made the above sure, it should work.

HTH!

Comment: Double checked everything, but i'm still getting the same problem. Is it possible it's an issue with the data it's trying to upload? Maybe a problem with the way the archive was created?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I needed to add `-copy_properties false -copy_permissions false` to my script, but it's not really clear to me why. Is this due to the documents in the archive not having properties or permissions?

Also this may be a topic for a separate question, but while XML and some binary files will now upload, the zip files in my archive will not.